How to block the internal cli tools verbose messages from printing?
This is an issue I have been having for some time and I have just not been able to find any solution to it.
Often times I have a PowerShell advanced function/ simple function that is using a native command internally. I want the function to have a seamless PowerShell experience, and I mostly achieved this except for whatever messages the cli might decide to print. Cli tools have "quiet" options, so I use that when I can but some don't have it.
For example calibre-convert has a -verbose flag but its only used to increase the number of output messages. The tool essentially does not have an option to turn of its messages.
I have tried a variety of things in PowerShell to get around this issue. For example, running either of the following lines always prints the following output:
calibre-convert inputBook.epub outputBook.pdf |out-null
$dump = calibre-convert inputBook.epub outputBook.pdf

The output:
qt.webenginecontext:

qt.webenginecontext:

GL Type: disabled
Surface Type: OpenGL
Surface Profile: NoProfile
Surface Version: 3.0
QSG RHI Backend: OpenGL
Using Supported QSG Backend: yes
Using Software Dynamic GL: yes
Using Multithreaded OpenGL: no

Init Parameters:
  *  application-name ebook-convert
  *  browser-subprocess-path C:\Program Files\Calibre2\app\bin\QtWebEngineProcess.exe
  *  disable-features ConsolidatedMovementXY,InstalledApp,BackgroundFetch,WebOTP,WebPayments,WebUSB,PictureInPicture
  *  disable-gpu
  *  disable-speech-api
  *  enable-features NetworkServiceInProcess,TracingServiceInProcess
  *  enable-threaded-compositing
  *  in-process-gpu
  *  use-gl disabled

Of course these messages have a purpose, I use them when I am writting my function, I just dont need them when in actual use as intend to do my own error handling.
powershell 7.4

It sounds like the unwanted messages print to stderr rather than stdout, so you need a 2>$null redirection to silence them (though this would also silence true error messages; use $LASTEXITCODE to determine if a call failed).

@mklement0 I did not think about stderr being a potential culprit, I will try your suggestion and also look into stderr as well, thank you.

[Void]calibre-convert inputBook.epub outputBook.pdf
$null = calibre-convert inputBook.epub outputBook.pdf

Maybe one of these will work ?

hmm, I will try this and see

@Ralf_Reddings: In effect, this is no different from $dump = calibre-convert inputBook.epub outputBook.pdf, as shown in the question (except that the latter quietly captures stdout output rather than discarding it), and therefore cannot be expected to make a difference.

Also, [Void]calibre-convert inputBook.epub outputBook.pdf causes a syntax error; the command line would need to be enclosed in (...) (which makes $null = ..., where the RHS does not need (...), syntactically more convenient).

mklement0 is right, this does not succeed in suppressing the message (I did give it ago a just to be sure)
